# Not able to invoke any of the constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Main");
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    }

}

class Test2 {

     Test2() {
         System.out.println("Inside Test2");
         //do something 
     }
     Test3 test = new Test3();

}

class Test3 {

     Test3() {
         System.out.println("Inside Test3");
         //do something  
     }
     Test2 test2 = new Test2();
}
```

Here I wanted to understand why this statement `Test2 test2 = new Test2();` in main method of class `Test` is not able to invoke the constructor of class `Test2` and similarly `Test3 test = new Test3();` in `Test2` is not able to invoke the constructor of class `Test3`.

Here I wanted to understand the reason for this behavior?

Expected Output : `Main Inside Test2 Inside Test3`
Current Output: `Main` with this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.practice.stackoverflow.Test3.<init>(Test.java:26)
    at com.practice.stackoverflow.Test2.<init>(Test.java:17)
    at com.practice.stackoverflow.Test3.<init>(Test.java:26)
```

Comment: In `Test2` you create a `Test3` which creates a `Test2` which creates a `Test3` which creates ...

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "Not able to invoke..." is not diagnostic (and it's incorrect). If you get an error, include the error in the post--nobody should have to ask.

Answer (score 4):

`Test2` makes a new `Test3` object... which makes a new `Test2` object... so on.

You are attempting to create an infinite amount of objects, so naturally you will get a StackOverflowError.

The following would work:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Main");
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
    }

}

class Test2 {

     Test2() {
         System.out.println("Inside Test2");
         //do something 
     }
     Test3 test = new Test3();

}

class Test3 {

     Test3() {
         System.out.println("Inside Test3");
         //do something  
     }
     Test4 test4 = new Test4();
}

class Test4 {
    Test4() {
        System.out.println("Inside Test4");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate how recursion is happening in my code, just wanted to understand the program execution flow in such above case by Java JVM.

Comment: Note that the order you're expecting these to print is actually *reversed*.

Comment: @MOnkey Step through your code, in your head or with a debugger. `Test2` has a member variable that's a `Test3`. `Test3` has a member variable that's a `Test2`. When you instantiate a `Test2` it initializes `test3` to a new `Test3`. When `Test3` is instantiated it initializes `test2` to a new `Test2`. The instantiation process does not change--this will go on until you run out of space.

Comment: @sleepToken, please correct me if my understanding is wrong here, so instance variables of class are always loaded first even before the constructor by JVM?

Comment: @MOnkey See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5. If you search for something like "java class instantiation order of execution" or similar you'll find easier reads than that, but that's the source.